# Keyboard and mouse connection issues

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a HP All In One desktop and I manually disconnected the mouse and keyboard internally from the (add a device) screen and I can't get reconnected to my computer?

Comment: Haven't you restarted your pc after doing that?

Comment: No I didn't restart it

Answer (score 1):

At first follow the steps below:

1.Reconnect the disconnected mouse and keyboard again using associated hardware ports.

2.Open **Device Manager** (Press **Win-key + R** and type `devmgmt.msc` in the box and hit enter).

3.In Device Manager, click your computer so that it is highlighted.

4.Click **Action**, and then click **Scan for hardware changes**.

5.After it finish installing check whether they work properly or not.

But if the above procedure fails to solve your issue, then restart your computer and hopefully this time those mouse and keyboard will be connected again.

Comment: No I have not tried to restart my PC

Comment: Restart your pc and let me know what happens now.

Comment: "Restarting your computer" may work for the OP but that isn't going to the root problem. SU is intended to be a database for others to look at in the future so this isn't really an acceptable answer, and should be a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/668230)

Comment: In this case, it maybe the exact right way to fix it - if the OP removed them from device manager, and replugging them in doesn't work, rebooting should 'in theory' get the new device wizard to pick them up and install them again...

Comment: @EricF I am really sorry about that....Thanks for the suggestion....actually at first what I wrote was the guaranteed solution, that's why I answered that way. May be, now it looks better. Thanks anyway.